# I think a pro is/are the sights

Tags: grammar

The context is talking about the pros and cons of a certain city. I'm not sure if the verb 'to be' should agree with the subject here or with the predicate, although I would say 'is'.

Comment: Verbs always agree with their subjects, not their complements.

Comment: For pros and cons, you have to say here: I think one of the pros is the sights.

Answer (score 0):

"Is" The verb should agree with the subject when it has a clear number.

But the sentence is badly phrased.  It can easily be improved by just swapping it around

> I think the sights are a pro.

But I don't like the use of "pro" here, and "sights" is a weak and generic word.

> The view from the top of the castle is one of the best things about the city.

There is a much better sentence.  It doesn't have the weak sense of "the sights", it is much more specific to this city. It doesn't have "pro" and there is no problem choosing "is/are". I've removed the "I think"; it is not required and removing it makes the sentence stronger. You can swap it around

> One of the best things about the city is the view from the top of the castle.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. I agree with all the stylistic changes you have made. I'm grading an essay and I didn't want to completely change what the student had written. (they used 'are')